# Java Sound on OSX no Port.Info Type supported

Tags: java, macos, audio, port

I try to simply playback a wav file using AudioSystem.Mixer interface First I tried to identify which mixer (device) has to be my output. The result is that no port type is supported. Whats wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class STest12{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Mixer.Info[] mi = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            Port.Info[] allePorts = {
                Port.Info.COMPACT_DISC,
                Port.Info.HEADPHONE,
                Port.Info.LINE_IN,
                Port.Info.LINE_OUT,
                Port.Info.MICROPHONE,
                Port.Info.SPEAKER
            };

            for (Mixer.Info mixerInfo : mi) {
                Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println(mixer.getMixerInfo().toString());

                for (Port.Info i : allePorts) {
                    System.out.println(i.toString() + " supported: " + mixer.isLineSupported(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is wrong, but the Java Sound API isn't implemented correctly on OSX.

Comment: This is more a comment than a solution.